# How to put button in ActionColumn at header only in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to put reset button under the action column only one time in GridView widget..

[image]

Any solution or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to override the renderFilterCellContent method of ActionColumn to achieve this. For yii1 you can refer to my WP post https://chinmaywaghmare.wordpress.com/2015/02/06/show-clear-filter-icon-in-filter-cell-of-yii-cgridview/ to get the idea how it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

To, put button in `ActionColumn` on header so, follow below steps:

1. Create a file **CustomActionColumn.php** in components folder.
2. Put below code in above file

   ```
   namespace app\components;

   use yii\grid\ActionColumn;
   use yii\helpers\Html;

   class CustomActionColumn extends ActionColumn
   {
        protected function renderFilterCellContent()
        {
           return Html::button('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
        }
   }
   ```
3. Now in your Gridview widget use `CustomActionColumn` instead of `ActionColumn`

   Like as

   ```
    [
      'class' => 'app\components\CustomButton',
    ],
   ```
4. Done.

**Note:-** Using these steps you can just display button in header.

Comment: You should try `[  'header' => 'Action',
   'class' => 'app\components\CustomButton',
 ],`

Answer (score 3):

Set header property of ActionColumn:

```
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '<div class="pull-right" >{update}{delete}</div>',
        'header' => '<button>Button</button>'
    ]
```

*Update:*

As already answered you can create custom column, and you may add only additional filter property so that you can customize this property for each grid.

```
class CustomActionColumn extends yii\grid\ActionColumn
{
     public $filter = "";
     protected function renderFilterCellContent()
     {
        return $this->filter;
     }
}
```

Then you set filter in grid definition:

```
[
   'class' => 'CustomActionColumn',
   'template' => '<div class="pull-right" >{update}{delete}</div>',
   'filter' => '<button>Button</button>'
]
```

Comment: Then you need to create  custom ActionColumn class and overide renderFilterCell method as answered by GAMITG.

Answer (score 2):

To display both a button and ActionColumn label you could override yii\grid\ActionColumn renderFilterCellContent() method with your own class like this:

```
namespace app\components;

class FilterActionColumn extends ActionColumn
{
    public $filterContent;

    /**
    * Renders the filter cell content.
    * The default implementation simply renders a blank space.
    * This method may be overridden to customize the rendering of the filter cell (if any).
    * @return string the rendering result
    */
    protected function renderFilterCellContent()
    {
        return $this->filterContent;
    }
}
```

Then you able to add both label and button to GridView replace default ActionColumn like this

1. In your view

   ```
   use app\components\FilterActionColumn;
   ```
2. Replace default GridView ActionColumn

   ```
   [
       'class' => FilterActionColumn::className(),
       // Add your own filterContent
       'filterContent' => Html::a('Your button', ['some/url'], [
           'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'title' => 'Some btn title',
       ]),
       'header'=> 'Your label',
       // Another ActionColumn options
       // ..   
   ],
   ```

You could see extended example here, i.e. if you need more than one button https://github.com/nick-denry/yii2-filter-action-column

Answer (score -2):

```
  GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'emptyCell' => Html::a('<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>&nbsp;Reset', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'style' => 'margin: 2px;']),
                    ]);
```

use emptyCell to set button...

Comment: This is going to fill all empty cells of gridview with a button!